# send POST parameters before submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, submit

I have the simple form

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" id="order" name="order" value="<?php echo order_id ?>" />
    <button  type="submit" name="order" form="form-order" id="button-send" title="My order"  onclick="send('http://myurl.com/data/send.php');"></button>
</form>
```

and aJax function:

```
function send(url) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,

        data: $('#order'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-send').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-send').button('reset');
        },
    });
}
```

all working, but before submit  I need post `order_id` to handle some additional information in send.php file and after that submit this info.
`order_id` I posting and storing it in `$_SESSION`. 
  It is possible to send `order_id` to the file before submit?

Comment: You should `return false` in your send function and then on the `complete` callback you could submit your form using `$('myForm').submit();`?

Comment: also can't send an element and need to send key/value pair

Comment: Putting it in a second ajax request?

Comment: I have tried suggestions but no luck... when I click button first time `order_id` saving in `$_SESSION` but  not submitting,  when click second time data submitting.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to send order_id to the file before submit?

**No.**

Sending, as you seem to put it, **means** submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem...
Instead to save `order_id` to the `$_session` I have passed it with send link

```
<button  type="submit" name="order" form="form-order" id="button-send" title="My order"  onclick="send('http://myurl.com/data/send.php?order_id=<?php echo order_id ?>');"></button>
```

And simply retrieved it in my send.php with `get` function and I get working all I need.
Thanks all for the help.